# Was there an early preview of Kagamigami or a similar series in Shonen Jump?

Tags: shonen-jump, kagamigami

Alright, so this is driving me crazy but I recently read the first issue of [Kagamigami](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=119149) that came out in Shonen Jump (I'm a few weeks behind). I remember reading another manga that felt almost the exact same as Kagamigami. In the manga I read, the crime takes place in a tunnel, not in front of stairs like in the recent issue. The evil Shikigami also wasn't called the "Ripper" I believe, and the main character didn't have a detailed discussion with the culprit like she does in this one.

The premise is almost the exact same: girl with power to trace objects becomes detective. The Shikigami that the boy uses are almost the exact same as the manga I remember reading. Besides re-downloading every issue of Shonen Jump, does anyone have an idea of what this might have been?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you may have read **Shikigami Twilight Days** (式神トワイライトデイズ), published in 2014 vol. 28, which is the one-shot predecessor to Kagamigami.

---

In case you're interested, I found this by using [this nifty Shounen Jump database](http://www.ktr.to/Comic/jump.html) and [searching for the author (Iwashiro Toshiaki / 岩代俊明)](http://www.ktr.to/Comic/yomikiri.cgi?start=1300&end=&order=0&keyword=%B4%E4%C2%E5%BD%D3%CC%C0&andor=0&example=) in the oneshots (読み切り) section at the bottom.

[Kagamigami's dic.pixiv page](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AC%E3%83%9F%E3%82%AC%E3%83%9F) verifies that Shikigami Twilight Days was the one-shot version of Kagamigami.

Comment: Seems that the Japanese issues have quite a different timeline than those in America. I found [this news article](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2014/07/21/psyen-authors-shikigami-twilight-days-one-shot-to-run-in-english-weekly-shonen-jump) on STDs (Shikigami Twilight Days, duh!). Which states that it was in the July 21st issue. This is incorrect, it was in the July 28th issue, No. 35.

Comment: The one-shot was definitely it! I have to say though, I definitely liked the one shot better than the first chapter, like what they did with the smiley faces and the cop. The only thing better in the first chapter was the enemy Shikigami.